# NSDictionary representation in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

From [CRToast](https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast) I want to write the following in Swift (This is from the [CRToast example](https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast#example)):

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                          kCRToastTextKey : @"Hello World!",
                          kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                          kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : [UIColor redColor],
                          kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                          kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                          kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionLeft),
                          kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionRight)
                          };

[CRToastManager showNotificationWithOptions:options
                            completionBlock:^{
                                NSLog(@"Completed");
                            }];
```

Here is my Swift representation of the first few lines:

```
var options:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [:]
options[kCRToastTextKey] = "Hello World !"
options[kCRToastTextAlignmentKey] = "\(NSTextAlignment.Center)"
options[kCRToastBackgroundColorKey] = UIColor.redColor()

CRToastManager.showNotificationWithOptions(options, completionBlock: { () -> Void in
      println("done!")
    })
```

When I compile and run the code I got the following error:

```
[CRToast] : ERROR given (Enum Value) for key kCRToastTextAlignmentKey was expecting Class __NSCFNumber but got Class Swift._NSContiguousString, passing default on instead
```

**What is the correct translation of the NSDictionary presented above in Swift?**

Comment: first off, you don't need those separate assignments. You can use a dictionary literal in Swift too. Now, the actual error is that the API apparently expects an `NSNumber` from the value corresponding to the text alignment key, but you are passing it a string instead.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant When you look at the example here: https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast#example you see that I works this way in ObjectiveC.

Comment: um, what are you talking about? there's nowhere any Swift code in that example… and the Objective-C code passes in an `NSNumber`, and so should your Swift code.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I want to translate the ObjectiveC code from the example to the correct Swift representation.

Comment: I know. And I have already told you what you need to do for that.

Comment: Try to use  NSNumber(NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue)

Comment: Is it ``.rawValue``?

Comment: Yes. I forgot that it is a property

Comment: @confile Pass `NSNumber(integer: NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSTextAlignment.Center is an enum, internally represented as an integer - but you are passing it as a string:

```
options[kCRToastTextAlignmentKey] = "\(NSTextAlignment.Center)"
```

whereas you should use the enum raw value:

```
options[kCRToastTextAlignmentKey] = NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue
```

Answer (score 1):

The API you are using apparently expects that the value for the text alignment enum be specified as an `NSNumber`, and not as a string. (that's not surprising - enums are integers in (Objective-)C.)

So, instead of using string interpolation, make an NSNumber out of the enum's value:

```
options[kCRToastTextAlignmentKey] = NSNumber(integer: NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue)
```

By the way, you don't need all those assignments. That's exactly the point in using a dictionary literal. You don't need to make the dictionary mutable then. Just do this:

```
let options:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [
  kCRToastTextKey: "Hello World !",
  kCRToastTextAlignmentKey: NSNumber(integer: NSTextAlignment.Center.rawValue),
  kCRToastBackgroundColorKey: UIColor.redColor()
]
```